# printing multi dimentional array

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

i have this multi dimentional array that i want to print into a table having each record/item go into its own row but it goes column wise. this is the output that im getting: http://mypetshopping.com/product.php

ps: the value of $product will by dynamic based on what product is being viewed.

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Hash</th>
<th>Quantity</th>
<th>Size</th>
<th>Color</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

<?php


  function addCart($product, $quantity, $size,$color) {

  $hash = md5($product);

  $_SESSION['cart'][$product]['name'] = $product;
  $_SESSION['cart'][$product]['hash'] = $hash;
  $_SESSION['cart'][$product]['quantity'] = $quantity;
  $_SESSION['cart'][$product]['size'] = $size;
  $_SESSION['cart'][$product]['color'] = $color;

  }

  addCart('Red Dress',1,'XL','red');
  addCart('Blue Dress',1,'XL','blue');
  addCart('Slippers',1,'XL','orange');
  addCart('Green Hat',1,'XXXL','green');

  $cart = $_SESSION['cart'];

  foreach($cart as $product => $array) {

    foreach($array as $key => $value) {

  ?>

    <tr>
    <td><?=$value;?></td>
    <td><?=$value;?></td>
    <td><?=$value;?></td>
    <td><?=$value;?></td>
    <td><?=$value;?></td>
    </tr>


  <?php


    }

  }


  ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your looping code should be written as:

```
<?php foreach( $cart as $product => $array ) { ?>
<tr>
    <?php foreach( $array as $key => $value ) { ?>
    <td><?php echo $value; ?></td>
    <?php } ?>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try altering your code to:

```
foreach($cart as $product => $array) { ?>
<tr>
<?php
    foreach($array as $key => $value) {
?>    
       <td><?=$value;?></td>

<?php


    }

?>
    </tr>

<?php

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
echo "<ul>";
for ( $layer = 0; $layer < 3; $layer++ )
{
    echo "<li>The layer number $layer";
    echo "<ul>";

    for ( $row = 0; $row < 3; $row++ )
    {
       echo "<li>The row number $row";
       echo "<ul>";

        for ( $col = 0; $col < 3; $col++ )
        {
            echo "<li>".$shop[$layer][$row][$col]."</li>";
        }
        echo "</ul>";
        echo "</li>";
    }
    echo "</ul>";
    echo "</li>";
}  
echo "</ul>";
?>
```

http://www.webcheatsheet.com/php/multidimensional_arrays.php